# JsonConvert SerializeObject ignore files / stream / System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

I'm using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` inside a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`.
Inside the `OnActionExecuting` I'm serializing the `filterContext.ActionParameters` for logging purpose.
The problem is that some of the actions are receiving files (`System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper`) via a `<from/>` with  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so i'm getting the error

> Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

What i want to do is ignore these kind of object which can't get serialize and could through errors.
I found out that i can ignore `class` `Properties` with `[JsonIgnore]` or `[ScriptIgnore]` attributes, but I'm looking for a more general solution becuase i don't want to place these attributes all over the place.
I also tried to research the `JsonSerializerSettings` object but didn't find something relevant to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter these parameters. somethink like:

```
var ToBeSerialized = filterContext.ActionParameters.Where(a=>a.Value.GetType()!=typeof(TheTypeYouWantToAvoid));

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ToBeSerialized);
```

Comment: Ok, nice approach, you need to fix your answer though to this: `.Where(a=>a.Value.GetType()!=typeof...` because we need to check the `Value` of each parameter of the action. (the `a` in this case is always a `<string><object>` member of a dictionary )

Comment: @Sag1v I didn't know that. I have not tested my code.I was giving a hint of the way it can be done. Thanks a lot for correcting my mistake